# using HttpSendHttpResponse for sending multi request without interrupt

Tags: c++, asynchronous, httpserver

i want sending requests for client without interrupt by HttpSendHttpResponse method
( microsoft http server api )

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686358(v=vs.85).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364499(v=vs.85).aspx

i use LPOVERLAPPED parameter in HttpSendHttpResponse 
but return error  "field with 997 overlapped i/o opration in progress"

because with this parameter we can sending second request only when first request is complete

how can i do without waiting ?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that error the same as should be expected? ERROR_IO_PENDING

> A synchronous call blocks until all response data specified in the pHttpResponse parameter is sent, whereas an asynchronous call immediately returns ERROR_IO_PENDING and the calling application then uses GetOverlappedResult or I/O completion ports to determine when the operation is completed.

In that case it is obviously not an error at all. Continue as described.